# C# / SQL : input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, syntax-error

I tried all the possibilities, I wrote

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@facultate", C1.Text); ' give me the same error..
```

I do not understand why.. and if I try to debug and see exactly what value it has and stopped at line

```
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@numar", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = int.Parse(T9.Text ) });
```

it stopped here and throws error:

> When converting a string to datetime, parse the string to take before putting each variable into the datetime object...
>
> make sure your method arguments are in the right format.

I can send the whole project with everything in.

```
const string sqlText = "INSERT INTO dbo.bd_formular(facultate,domeniul,specializare,forma_invatamant,d_inscriere,nume_prenume,cod,localitate,judet,tara,strada,numar,bloc,scara,etaj,apartament,sector,cod_p,data_nasterii,locul_nasterii,judet_n,tara_n,sex,stare_civila,cetatenie,cetatenie_op,etnie,incadrare,cnp,serie,numar_cnp,eliberat,e_data,studii_preuni,nume_unitate,spec_fili_profil,oras_s,judet_s,tara_s,forma_de_invatamant,medie_bac,durata_studii,data_absolvirii,tipul_diploma,seria_diploma,numarul_diploma,emis_de_catre,data_emiterii,nr_foi_matricole,introducere_date,semnatura) VALUES (@facultate,@domeniul,@specializare,@forma_invatamant,@d_inscriere,@nume_prenume,@cod,@localitate,@judet,@tara,@strada,@numar,@bloc,@scara,@etaj,@apartament,@sector,@cod_p,@data_nasterii,@locul_nasterii,@judet_n,@tara_n,@sex,@stare_civila,@cetatenie,@cetatenie_op,@etnie,@incadrare,@cnp,@serie,@numar_cnp,@eliberat,@e_data,@studii_preuni,@nume_unitate,@spec_fili_profil,@oras_s,@,@judet_s,@tara_s,@forma_de_invatamant,@medie_bac,@durata_studii,@data_absolvirii,@tipul_diploma,@seria_diploma,@numarul_diploma,@emis_de_catre,@data_emiterii,@nr_foi_matricole,@introducere_date,@semnatura)";

using (var con = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString))
using (var comm = new SqlCommand(sqlText, con))
{
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@facultate", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = C1.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@domeniul", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T1.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@specializare", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T2.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@forma_invatamant", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = C2.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@d_inscriere", SqlDbType.Date) { Value = DTP1.Value.ToString() });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nume_prenume", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T3.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cod", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T4.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@localitate", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T5.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@judet", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T6.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tara", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T7.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@strada", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T8.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@numar", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = int.Parse(T9.Text ) });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@bloc", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T10.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@scara", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = int.Parse(T11.Text) });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@etaj", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = int.Parse(T12.Text) });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@apartament", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = int.Parse(T3.Text) });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sector", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T14.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cod_p", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = int.Parse(T15.Text) });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data_nasterii", SqlDbType.Date) { Value = DTP2.Value.ToString() });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@locul_nasterii", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T16.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@judet_n", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T17.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tara_n", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T18.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sex", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = C3.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@stare_civila", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = C4.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cetatenie", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = C5.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cetatenie_op", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = int.Parse(T19.Text) });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@etnie", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T20.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@incadrare", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = C6.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cnp", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = int.Parse(T21.Text) });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@serie", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T22.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@numar_cnp", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = T23.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@eliberat", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T24.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@e_data", SqlDbType.Date) { Value = DTP3.Value.ToString() });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@studii_preuni", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = C7.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nume_unitate", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T25.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@spec_fili_profil", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T26.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@oras_s", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T27.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@judet_s", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T28.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tara_s", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T29.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@forma_de_invatamant", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = C8.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@medie_bac", SqlDbType.Decimal) { Value = decimal.Parse(T30.Text) });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@durata_studii", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = int.Parse(C9.Text) });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data_absolvirii", SqlDbType.Date) { Value = DTP4.Value.ToString() });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tipul_diploma", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = C10.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@serie_diploma", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T31.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@numar_diploma", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = int.Parse(T32.Text) });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@emis_de_catre", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T33.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data_emiterii", SqlDbType.Date) { Value = DTP5.Value.ToString() });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@nr_foi_matricole", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = int.Parse(T34.Text) });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@introducere_date", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T35.Text });
    comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@semnatura", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = T36.Text });

    con.Open();
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

SQL table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tabela_form] 
(
            [facultate]               VARCHAR (100) primary key  NOT NULL,
            [domeniul]                VARCHAR (100)  NOT NULL,
            [specializare]            VARCHAR (100)  NOT NULL,
            [forma_invatamant]        VARCHAR (100)  NOT NULL,
            [d_inscriere]             DATE           NOT NULL,
            [nume_prenume]            VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
            [cod]                     VARCHAR (10)   NOT NULL,
            [localitate]              VARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
            [judet]                   VARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
            [tara]                    VARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
            [strada]                  VARCHAR (15)   NOT NULL,
            [numar]                   INT            NOT NULL,
            [bloc]                    VARCHAR (5)    NOT NULL,
            [scara]                   VARCHAR (5)    NOT NULL,
            [etaj]                    INT            NOT NULL,
            [apartament]              INT            NOT NULL,
            [sector]                  VARCHAR (1)    NOT NULL,
            [cod_p]                   INT            NOT NULL,
            [data_nasterii]           DATE           NOT NULL,
            [locul_nasterii]          VARBINARY (50) NOT NULL,
            [judet_n]                 VARCHAR (15)   NOT NULL,
            [tara_n]                  VARCHAR (15)   NOT NULL,
            [sex]                     VARCHAR (7)    NOT NULL,
            [stare_civila]            VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
            [cetatenie]               VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
            [cetatenie_op]            VARCHAR(50)            NULL,
            [etnie]                   VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
            [incadrare]               VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
            [cnp]                     INT            NOT NULL,
            [serie]                   VARCHAR (2)    NOT NULL,
            [numar_cnp]               INT            NOT NULL,
            [eliberat]                VARCHAR (10)   NOT NULL,
            [e_data]                  DATE           NOT NULL,
            [studii_preuni]           VARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
            [nume_unitate]            VARCHAR (30)   NOT NULL,
            [spec_fili_profil]        VARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
            [oras_s]                  VARCHAR (15)   NOT NULL,
            [judet_s]                 VARCHAR (15)   NOT NULL,
            [tara_s]                  VARCHAR (15)   NOT NULL,
            [forma_de_invatamant]     VARCHAR (30)   NOT NULL,
            [medie_bac]               DECIMAL (2, 2) NOT NULL,
            [durata_studii]           INT            NOT NULL,
            [data_absolvirii]         DATE           NOT NULL,
            [tipul_diploma]           VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
            [seria_diploma]           VARCHAR (10)   NOT NULL,
            [numarul_diploma]         INT            NOT NULL,
            [emis_de_catre]           VARCHAR (100)  NOT NULL,
            [data_emiterii]           DATE           NOT NULL,
            [nr_foi_matricole]        INT            NOT NULL,
            [diploma_bac_original]    VARCHAR (2)    NULL,
            [adeverinta_original]     VARCHAR (2)    NULL,
            [adeverinta_legalizata]   VARCHAR (2)    NULL,
            [original_atestat]        VARCHAR (2)    NULL,
            [atestat_legalizat]       VARCHAR (2)    NULL,
            [cerficat_legalizat]      VARCHAR (2)    NULL,
            [cerificat_cas_legalizat] VARCHAR (2)    NULL,
            [foto_3_4_da]             VARCHAR (2)    NULL,
            [foto_3_4_nu]             VARCHAR (2)    NULL,
            [copie_buletin_da]        VARCHAR (2)    NULL,
            [copie_buletin_nu]        VARCHAR (2)    NULL,
            [foaie_matricola_da]      VARCHAR (2)    NULL,
            [foaie_matricola_nu]      VARCHAR (2)    NULL,
            [bon_achitare_da]         VARCHAR (2)    NULL,
            [bon_achitare_nu]         VARCHAR (2)    NULL,
            [introducere_date]        VARCHAR (30)   NOT NULL,
            [semnatura]               VARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: could you pleas explain why are you passing date as string comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@data_nasterii", SqlDbType.Date) { Value = DTP2.Value.ToString() });

Comment: Because i take the value from DateTimerPicker..if it is not right that what should i have to change .. if you can tell me..

Comment: FYI: You can use the overload of `Add` to shorten something like `comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(name, type) { Value = val});` to `comm.Parameters.Add(name, type).Value = val;`